# chrome redirect to mobile version of the website on a desktop

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, redirect, mobile, user-agent

Chrome redirects to mobile version, on a desktop.

I have a website and it has a iphone version that redirect iphones and safari users to a mobile version of the website.

The chrome browser on a desktop redirect also to the iphone/mobile version of the website.
Only this i dont want.
Other browsers like Mozilla and internet explore are working fine.

In my .htaccess file i have :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/iphone/
RewriteRule .* /iphone/ [R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Safari
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/iphone/
RewriteRule .* /iphone/ [R]
```

i have searched the web for many hour before asking here. 
is there anyone who have experience with this type of bugs.

The website is html5, no php is used.

Regards iamdaves

Answer (score 0):

Looking [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/) you can see that the user agent string for Chrome also includes the keyword 'Safari'. Thus you might want to use something else to detect just the Safari browser.

```
Chrome 37.0.2049.0
    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36
```

Perhaps 'Macintosh' or 'Mac OS'

```
Safari 5.1.7
    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.13+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2
```

Examples from [www.useragentstring.com](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php)

Comment: Thank you CDspace this helped a lot.